# AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'menu'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

[image]I am still new to kivymd and I still struggle with programming generally. I am trying to make a drop-down list for one of my screens. I suspect I am doing something fairly stupid and it's really obvious but I can't for the life of me understand what it is. When pressing my dropdown I get an error.

I have placed the dropdown in the screen titled "Create Case Version 2.0" as I am trying to play around with the spacing etc. It's labelled "testing" atm

As always any help is massively appreciated:

```py
from kivy import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationLayout, MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineAvatarListItem, ILeftBody, OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.metrics import dp


Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList, Screen):
    pass


class NavLayout(MDNavigationLayout):
    pass


class Login(Screen):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class Nav(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    ScreenManager = ObjectProperty


class IconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class Homepage(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


    def submit(self):
        Popup(title='Submitted', content=Label(text='Case has been submitted and will be reviewed'), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5)).open()
        sm = self.ids.screen_manager
        scr = sm.get_screen('Create Case')
        for child in scr.children:
            if isinstance(child, TextInput):
                child.text = ''

    def dropdown(self):
        self.menu_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "IconListItem",
            "icon": "git",
            "text": f"Item {i}",
            "height": dp(56),
            "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.set_item(x),
            } for i in range(5)
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.drop_item,
            items=self.menu_items,
            position="center",
            width_mult=4,
        )
        self.menu.bind()

    def set_item(self, text_item):
        self.screen.ids.drop_item.set_item(text_item)
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen



class AddNewCustomer(Screen):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()





class AddNewStaff(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    Login = ObjectProperty()


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Window.maximize()
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        # self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "900"
        login = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
        return login


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

```
ScreenManager:
    Login:
    Homepage:
    AddNewCustomer:
    Nav:
    DrawerList:

<Login>:
    name: "login"
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 700, 800
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Image:
            source: 'images/asteria.png'
            size: 100, 200

        MDLabel:
            id: login
            font_size: 40
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 15

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: user
            hint_text: "username"
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            hint_text: "password"
            icon_right: "eye-off"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            password: True

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "LOGIN"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "homepage"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "CLEAR"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: app.clear()


        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50


<Nav>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Add New Customer"

                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewCustomer"
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "right"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Add New Staff"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewStaff"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Case List"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "caseList"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Create Case"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.screen_manager.current = "Create Case"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Create Case Version 2.0"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.screen_manager.current = "Create Case Version 2.0"



            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Log Out"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

                    root.manager.current = "login"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"



<Homepage>:
    name: "homepage"
    Screen:

        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: "Homepage"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Welcome Home"
                        halign: "center"


                Screen:
                    name: "addNewCustomer"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New customer"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "addNewStaff"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New Staff"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "caseList"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case List"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "casePool"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Pool"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "Create Case"


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Title"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.875, "center_x": 0.115}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: CaseTitle
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.155}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.791, "center_x": 0.115}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.779, "center_x": 0.155}


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Forename"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.115}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Forename
                        hint_text: "Info here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 137.5
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.121}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Surname"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.210}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Forename
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 137.5
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.210}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative email"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.620, "center_x": 0.115}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative Email
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.600, "center_x": 0.155}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative Phone"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.533, "center_x": 0.115}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative phone
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.513, "center_x": 0.155}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Source"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.449, "center_x": 0.115}

                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Case Source
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.437, "center_x": 0.155}








                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Priority"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.365, "center_x": 0.115}

                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Case Priority
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.353, "center_x": 0.155}




                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Category"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.281, "center_x": 0.115}








                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Description"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.883, "center_x": 0.360}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: CaseDescription
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.400}







                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Possible Cases"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.799, "center_x": 0.360}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: PossibleCases
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.780, "center_x": 0.400}







                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Knowledge Helper"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.715, "center_x": 0.360}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: KnowledgeHelper
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.697, "center_x": 0.400}




                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        text: "Submit"
                        font_size: 12
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.400,"center_x": 0.5}
                        on_release: root.submit()




                Screen:
                    name: "Create Case Version 2.0"


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Title"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.875, "center_x": 0.115}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: CaseTitle
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.155}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.791, "center_x": 0.115}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.779, "center_x": 0.155}


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Forename"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.115}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Forename
                        hint_text: "Info here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 137.5
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.121}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Surname"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.210}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Forename
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 137.5
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.210}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative email"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.620, "center_x": 0.115}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative Email
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.600, "center_x": 0.155}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative Phone"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.533, "center_x": 0.115}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative phone
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.513, "center_x": 0.155}



                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Source"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.449, "center_x": 0.115}

                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Case Source
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.437, "center_x": 0.155}








                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Priority"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.365, "center_x": 0.115}

                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Case Priority
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.353, "center_x": 0.155}




                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Category"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.281, "center_x": 0.115}

                    MDDropDownItem:
                        id: drop_item
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        text: 'testing'
                        on_release: app.menu.open()











                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Description"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.883, "center_x": 0.360}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: CaseDescription
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.400}







                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Possible Cases"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.799, "center_x": 0.360}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: PossibleCases
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.780, "center_x": 0.400}







                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Knowledge Helper"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.715, "center_x": 0.360}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: KnowledgeHelper
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.697, "center_x": 0.400}




                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        text: "Submit"
                        font_size: 12
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.400,"center_x": 0.5}
                        on_release: root.submit()







        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                title: 'Navigation'

                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('open')]]
                right_action_items: [["images/asteria.png", lambda x: None]]



                elevation:5


            Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            Nav:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
                manager: root.manager
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `kv` file, you have:

```
on_release: app.menu.open()
```

but, as the error says, the `App` class has no `menu` attribute. You have code in your post that looks like it will create a `menu` attribute in the `Homepage` class, but it is never called. If that is the `menu` that you want to use, I suggest changing your `kv` to access that `menu`:

```
                MDDropDownItem:
                    id: drop_item
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    text: 'testing'
                    on_release: root.menu.open()  # access Homepage menu
```

And add code to make sure that the `menu` is created:

```
class Homepage(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Homepage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown()
```

There are other errors in your code, but this should correct that one problem.

Comment: I did try this, but now I just get an error AttributeError: 'Homepage' object has no attribute 'screen'

Comment: TypeError: RelativeLayout.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: As I said, there are additional errors in your code. If you need help solving them, post a new question.